# Bonjour on Windows 7 Registration of Servers does not last

Tags: windows, bonjour

Using Bonjour Registration Service on Windows 7 and am having an issue with the service saying "active" and "discoverable" after an amount of time, about 5-10 mins or so.

Have duplicated the problem with the command line tool

```
dns-sd -R CMD-TEST  _test._tcp "" 4667
```

Using various tools on windows and IOS (Discovery), the service will appear for about 5 mins and then vanish with the command line tool and / or with code.  On IOS with the same code it does not vanish.

Any hints / clues on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 5353 has to be open for incoming and outgoing UDP.